ECS Task Failure Alerts Notification
I have ECS Services running and I want to setup a alert on Task count failure.
That is if during new deployments the container is not stable and Tasks are failing .
I want to generate a Alert Notification if the failure count is more than 5 times.
Currently i have setup The alert with The event bridge but the problem is It sends the alert during new deployment when old running task is stopped and is replaced with new one.
To fix this i want 5 failure counts so that it will be considered as container is not stable and for the actions to be taken.
I want any suggestions or way to achieve this functionality,
I was thinking about creating the lambda functions, but if there is any simple solution,Please Let me know
